# How to create and activate conda env in one line?

Tags: python, conda

It often happens that when I create a conda environment, I forgot about activating it, despite the clear conda message. And I end up installing my packages in the conda **base** environment. (yeah... I'm a bit of a dreamer)

My questions are:

1. Are there use cases where you create a conda environment but don't activate it right after?
2. How to create a conda environment and activate it in a single line? (in a Linux prompt shell, and non-interactive)

Answer (score 2):

As a concrete example in answer to your first question, I have used `conda` as a way to wrap a disposable build environment in some `Makefile` targets, i.e., I create the environment, and then subsequent commands or targets may make use of the environment via `conda run`.

Adapting a snippet from one `Makefile`, you could create a function in a `bash` startup file:

```
    conda_create_and_run() {
        ENV_NAME=$1
        CONDA_PY_VER=$2
        . ${CONDA_ENV_FILE}
        conda config --append envs_dirs ${CONDA_DIR}
        conda create -p ${CONDA_DIR}/${ENV_NAME} python=${CONDA_PY_VER} -y
        conda activate ${ENV_NAME}
    }
```

Here `CONDA_PY_VER` is the non-default `python` version you want the environment to possibly be created with, and `CONDA_DIR` and `CONDA_ENV_FILE` are, respectively, the location where `conda` keeps its environments and the `conda` environment file you need to source (or have part of your shell init) in order to have the `conda` commands available.

You would then use it as:

```
conda_create_and_run myenv 3.8
```

to create an environment for `python3.8` named `myenv`.